# Is there a (semiclassical) electric field operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, semiclassical

So I come from a chemistry background, where the electronic structure of atoms and molecules is central. For practical purposes, we usually work with a charge density operator

$$ \hat{\rho}(r) = q \delta (r-r')  \; ,$$

with $r'$ being the "particle coordinate" so that the expectation value is

$$ \langle \Psi|\hat{\rho}(r)|\Psi\rangle = \int \left| \Psi (r')\right|^2 q \delta (r-r') \;dr' = q  \left| \Psi (r)\right|^2  \; ,$$

in accordance with the idea of the probability being proportional to the wavefunction squared.

Then, in some electrodynamics exercises (eg. in Jackson) we take this charge density, then solve Gauss's equation for the electric field, and conclude that the electric field of the quantum mechanical system is given by our result.

I'm wondering: is there some operator $\hat{E}(r)$ that would give us back this semiclassical electric field as  $\langle \Psi|\hat{E}(r)|\Psi\rangle $?

Maybe I am using semiclassical wrong in this context, in my understanding if I get my charge density from quantum mechanics but solve the classical Maxwell equations, that can be called semiclassical. I am also aware that the electric field operator is defined in quantum electrodynamics as acting on the modes of the field, but I don't think I am looking for that operator (as I am not interested in field-matter interactions), nor can I understand QED derivations with a chemistry background sadly.

I've found [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5018399) which introduced a polarization operator $\hat{P}(r)$ so that the polarization field will be the solution of Gauss's equation for the charge density (Eq. 3 of the paper), which seems to be similar to what I am looking for. I am wondering: is this polarization field the same as the electric field in this context? My understanding is that we can only get a well defined longitudinal field component by solving Gauss's equation, so it might very well be that the longitudinal component of this polarization field is the same as of the electric field that I am looking for.

So is there such an operator that would have the electric field of the charge density corresponding to our wavefunction as the expectation operator? And if yes, how is that different from the polarization field operator?

---

**EDIT** for clarity, let's consider the example of a hydrogen atom.

The electronic wavefunction of the ground state of the hydrogen atom is (in the simplest units)

$$\Psi(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp{(-r)} \; .$$

I want to find the electric field of this electron. In order to do this, I'll first evaluate the classical charge density, then solve Gauss's law for the field.

The charge density - and here we employ the semiclassical idea - will be given as the expectation value of the charge density operator

$$ \rho(r) = \int \left| \Psi (r')\right|^2 q \delta (r-r') \;dr' = \frac{q}{\pi} \exp{(-2r)}\; .$$

To get the field from this classical charge density I just solve Gauss's law for the field

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \rho \; \rightarrow \;  \vec{E}(r) = -\frac{q e^{-2 r} \left(2 r^2+2 r+1\right)}{4 \pi r^2 } \hat{e}_r \; .$$

This idea is clear to me.

My first question is:

1. Is there an operator directly for the electric field, so that instead of evaluating first the expectation value of $\hat{\rho}$ and solving Gauss's law I could directly evaluate $\hat{E}$?

While researching this question I've came across the concept of the polarization density. I am not familiar with polarization calculations at all, but to me it seems like there's an intimate connection between the electric field and the polarization field in this context. To be more exact, in [this paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1973.0020) Eq. 29 is exactly what I find for the electric field for the hydrogen atom, however in the paper it is claimed that it is the polarization field of the atom.

My second question is:

2. Is this electric field operator that I am looking for exactly the same as the polarization field operator? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: "Semi-classical" usually means fields are wave-like; i.e., no field operators.

Comment: Formally we may write $E:=-\nabla_x \phi$, where $\phi(x,x'')=\int d^3x' \frac{q \delta(x''-x')}{|x-x'|}$ which, when averaged over a given state, looks like $\left<\psi|E(x)|\psi\right>=\int d^3x''\ \psi^*(x'')\left[-\nabla_x \phi \right] \psi(x'')$. No new information has been added with this formalism, this still amounts to finding the field due to the current density defined in your post.

Answer (score 0):

As long as we talk about quantum mechanics, the electromagnetic field is usually taken to be non-quantized (unlike the electrons and nuclei of the atoms). That is, there is no need for introducing field operators and wave functions. The situation changes in quantum field theory, where one quantized the particles and the elecytromagnetic field on equal footing, and one can introduce the operators in the standard way, see [Quantization of the electromagnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field) (and also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/542483/247642)). However, this is largely beyond the scope of what seems to be required in the case of the OP.

**Update:**
The particular ways of solving the Poisson equation for the electric potential, $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\nabla^2\phi(\mathbf{r})=\rho(\mathbf{r})$$
is by using [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function), that is the solution of the equation for a point charge:
$$\nabla^2G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')=\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'),$$
which gives us
$$
G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')=\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}- \mathbf{r}'|}.
$$
The potential from charge distribution $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ can now be written as
$$
\phi(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d^3\mathbf{r}'\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}- \mathbf{r}'|}.$$
One could also obtain a similar solution directly for the field, by defining a function $$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r},(\mathbf{r})')=\nabla_\mathbf{r}\cdot G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')$$
(Working directly with the field is however less practical, since one needs to take care of all its components.)

See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/132875/247642).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; it seems like my understanding of the semiclassical idea was in the right ballpark. My question - that is, asking for an operator for the nonquantized electric field - still makes sense though, right?

Comment: In classical electrodynamics one usually doesn't deal wuth operators... In Schrödinger equation we simply include $E(x,t)$, as if it is a function - liek potential. Tht is, it is an operator in respect to electrons, as any function dependent on $x$. Btw, isn't "croissant" masculine - "le beau croissant"?

Comment: I think including E(x,t) into the Schrodinger equation is usually done when my quantum system is in an external field. However, if I am interested in the field generated by the system, I think that should be able to be expressed with an operator, just as I can express the charge density of my system with an operator.

Comment: You need not make the external field into the operator - however now your external field is not a given function, but obeys its own equations, which are the classical Maxwell equations.

Comment: Sadly I don't see how that helps me to find the electric field of a quantum system without any external field present.

Comment: Quantum system in your case is charge particles. The electric field is produced by their charge - for this you need to plug the expectation value of thsi charge (i.e., of $\hat{\rho}$) into the Maxwell equations (or whatever is more suitable in yoru case), but the field remains classical. I suggest that you ask a question  with more specific details of the calculation that you are trying to do.

Comment: What I want to ask in the question is: instead of finding the expectation value of the charge and putting that into Maxwell's equation, is there an operator for the electric field that I could directly evaluate (circumventing the charge density altogether). I was hoping this was clear in the question, but maybe I should try to improve it.

Comment: You may be able to express your solution in terms of $\hat{\rho}$ and only then average it. And you do not necessarily have to solve the Maxwell equations head on - you seem to have already encountered the polarization calculations. But it is not clear what you are really trying to do - your question is very general... and not very precisely framed from the physicist's point of view.

Comment: I've tried to improve the question with a more concrete example...

Comment: I expanded my answer - perhaps it helps more now.